# Making a Legend in a Scattergeo Plot in Plotly

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend, plotly

I'm plotting some data similar to the first example found [here](https://plot.ly/python/scatter-plots-on-maps/) (the US airports map). However, rather than plotting a scale I'm plotting binary features (let's say one color is over 15k flights and one color is under 15k flights). I've looked at the documentation but can't find a way to do a legend if I wanted to do this sort of plot. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could specify the color according to your condition, e.g.

```
color = np.where(df['Set'] > 15000, 'red', 'green')
```

but then you wouldn't have a nice legend.

An alternative approach would be to add two plots, one for each condition.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2011_february_us_airport_traffic.csv')

data = dict(
        type = 'scattergeo',
        locationmode = 'USA-states', 
        mode = 'markers'
        )

data_high = data.copy()
data_high['lon'] = df[df['cnt']  > 10000 ]['long']
data_high['lat'] = df[df['cnt']  > 10000 ]['lat']
data_high['marker'] = dict(color = 'red')
data_high['name'] = '> 10000'

data_low = data.copy()
data_low['lon'] = df[df['cnt']  <= 10000 ]['long']
data_low['lat'] = df[df['cnt']  <= 10000 ]['lat']
data_low['marker'] = dict(color = 'green')
data_low['name'] = '<= 10000'

layout = dict(
        geo = dict(
            scope = 'usa',
            projection = dict(type='albers usa'),
        ),
    )

fig = dict(data=[data_high, data_low], layout=layout)
plotly.offline.plot(fig)
```

Comment: Thanks! You've been very helpful in helping me understand plotly.